# add and remove linkedlist with conditions

Tags: java, class, object, linked-list

So.. I've been staring at this programming assignment for a few hours already and I've went through all my lecture notes,exercises and google on how to do this but I still can't. I'm not even sorry for practically pasting my entire homework here. :D Basically, I need to add and remove Lots in parkingLots.

For example, “ADD 5 3” means to add 3 lots, starting from lot 5, to the list of occupied lots. Hence, lots 5, 6, 7 will be given to an incoming fleet of 3 cars, if the request is successful.
Likewise, “REMOVE 10 2” means to free up the 2 occupied lots 10 and 11 when 2 cars leave the car park, if the request is successful.

An ADD request is not successful if any of the requested lots is already occupied. In this case, none of the requested lots will be added to the list of occupied lots.

A REMOVE request is not successful if any of the requested lots is vacant. In this case, none of the lots will be removed from the list of occupied lots.

Start + size does not exceed 1000; if it does, the request is considered invalid and no action will be taken.

The nodes in the list are maintained in ascending order of start value.

My thought process is as such
After reading in the starting lot and lot size, check whether it clashes with a previous lot or the next lot. If it does then don't do anything. If it doesn't then add. T

he iterator in the toString() method will cover the printing issue of printing the first lot of what size followed by the next lot so on and so forth.

I'm having a huge problem adding and removing because the LinkedList only takes in the position but it does not take in the size. For example if the start is 12 and the lots are 2, technically it should take up 12 and 13 but the code is such that it adds a Lot object at 12 and the position 13 in the LinkedList is empty. This will give me problems if I want to check whether the Lot on the LinkedList is occupied or not as by right, only one position is taken up.

```
public class ParkingManager {
 12 
 13     private static final int LAST_LOT = 1000;
 14     private LinkedList <Lots> parkingLots;
 15 
 16     public ParkingManager() {
 17         parkingLots = new LinkedList<Lots>();
 18     }
 19 
 20     public void addLots(int start, int size) {
 21     
 22             
 23     }       
 24     
 25     public void removeLots(int start, int size) {
 26         
 27     }   
 28     
 29     // Returns the string representation of the linked list
 30     public String toString() {
 31         String str = "";
 32         Iterator itr = parkingLots.iterator();
 33         if (itr.hasNext())
 34             str += itr.next();
 35         while (itr.hasNext()) {
 36             str += "->" + itr.next();
 37         }   
 38         return str;
 39     }   
 40     
 41     public static void main(String[] args) {
 42     
 43         ParkingManager pm = new ParkingManager();
 44         Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 45         String op;
 46         int start, size;
 47 
 48         while (sc.hasNext()) {
 49             op = sc.next();
 50             start = sc.nextInt();
 51             size = sc.nextInt();
 52             // System.out.println(op + " " + start + " " + size); // For checking
 53             if (op.equals("ADD")) {
 54                 pm.addLots(start, size);
 55             }
 56             else if (op.equals("REMOVE")) {
 57                 pm.removeLots(start, size);
 58             }
 59             System.out.println(pm);
 60         }
 61     }
 62 }
```

This is the Lots class

```
class Lots {
  6 
  7     /****** Attributes *********/
  8     int lotStart; // start lot number in the group
  9     int lotSize;  // how many lots are there in this group?
 10 
 11     /******* Constructors ********/
 12     public Lots() {
 13     }
 14 
 15     public Lots(int start, int size) {
 16         setLotStart(start);
 17         setLotSize(size);
 18     }
 19 
 20     /******** Accessors *******/
 21     public int getLotStart() {
 22         return lotStart;
 23     }
 24 
 25     public int getLotSize() {
 26         return lotSize;
 27     }
 28 
 29     /********* Mutators ********/
 30     public void setLotStart(int start) {
 31         lotStart = start;
 32     }
 33 
 34     public void setLotSize(int size) {
 35         lotSize = size;
 36     }
 37 
 38     public String toString() {
 39         return "[" + getLotStart() + ";" + getLotSize() + "]";
 40     }
 41 }
 42
```

Sample run (input is bolded):
**ADD 100 100**
[100;100]
**REMOVE 150 10**
[100;50]->[160;40]
**REMOVE 145 10**
[100;50]->[160;40]
**REMOVE 100 10**
[110;40]->[160;40]
**REMOVE 190 10**
[110;40]->[160;30]
**REMOVE 120 8**
[110;10]->[128;22]->[160;30]
(user enters ctrl-d here)

I'm dying here. Please help :(

Comment: You said "the code is such that" but your addLots() is empty so it looks like you haven't tried. Stop trying to think in terms of doing it in a single operation and consider a for loop of individual adds.

Comment: yea thats cost that's the part i need to fill. I'm still trying! thanks

Comment: I've tried iterator.
I've tried many boolean if statements to detect if a location on the LinkedList is occupied by a lot.
I'm currently trying a for loop with a set of boolean if statements.